# Entering text into a docker container via ssh from bash file

Tags: bash, docker

What I am trying to do is setup a local development database and to prevent  everyone having to go through all the steps I thought it would be useful to create a script.

What I have below stop once it is in the terminal, which looks like:

**output**

```
./dbSetup.sh 
hash of container 0d1b182aa6f1
/ #
```

At which point I have to manually enter `exit`.

**script**

```
#!/bin/bash
command=$(docker ps | grep personal)
set $command
echo "hash of container ${1}"
docker exec -it ${1} sh
```

Is there a way I can inject a command via a script into a dockers container terminal?

Answer (score 0):

In order to execute command inside a container, you can use something like this:

```
docker exec -ti my_container sh -c "echo a && echo b"
```

More information available at: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/

Answer (score 0):

Your script finds a running Docker container and opens a shell to it. The "-it" makes it interactive and allocates a tty which is why it continues to wait for input, e.g. "exit". If the plan is to execute some commands to initialize a local development database, I'd recommend looking at building an image with a Dockerfile instead. i.e. Once you figure out the commands to run, they would become RUN commands and the container after docker run would expose a local development database.

If you really want some commands to run within the shell after it is started and maintain the session, depending on the base image, you might be able to mount a bash profile that has the required commands, e.g. -v db_profile:/etc/profile.d where db_profile is a folder with the shell scripts you want to run. To get them to run you'd exec sh -l to have the login startup scripts to run.